# Adding transparent overlay to div

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to add an overlay over a `div` which houses an image. I've seen approaches which add an overlay to background images, but can't seem to figure out why it doesn't work for divs?

Approach:

```css
.featured-image {
  height: 338px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.overlay {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="featured-image">
  <div class="overlay">
    <img src="https://img.freepik.com/free-vector/abstract-low-poly-design-background_1048-8196.jpg?size=338c&ext=jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```html
<style>
.featured-image {
  height: 338px;
  position: relative;
}

.overlay {
  position:absolute;
  top:0px;
  left:0px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
}
</style>
<div class="featured-image">
  <div class="overlay"></div>
    <img src="https://img.freepik.com/free-vector/abstract-low-poly-design-background_1048-8196.jpg?size=338c&ext=jpg">
  
</div>
```